# Qt and Digia licensing

Tags: qt, sdk, licensing

I wanted to download Qt sdk today and found that nokia site doesn't work now. I was redirected to digia [site](http://qt.digia.com/Product/):. I founded, that now I can't just download open licensed sdk. They requires my name and other info. In email they sent me I founded the links for commercial version of SDK and my license key.

Why did they do this? Would it be free for use in future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the website says, if you want the Qt Open Source version, you have to go to [Qt Project website](http://qt-project.org/).

The copyright holders can change the license as they please.  This is usually easier when all the copyright is hold by one single entity.  Sill you can take the Free/Open Source versions and continue working with that.

As far as I know, Qt have had dual license since they opened it.  What Digia seems to be doing is distributing the one that has a proprietary license, leaving to the project to distribute the open one.